# #enable-offline-mode no longer in Chrome rev 39

Tags: google-chrome, caching, proxy, offline

I'm developing a kiosk-mode wordpress site for a client which has to work offline on a PC with Windows 8 and automatically update when back online and new content is available.

According to [this](http://addyosmani.com/blog/offline-mode-chrome/) website, Chrome rev 35-37 used to have this ability (through the flag #enable-offline-mode), however in rev 39 this flag is gone. Instead, I have the ability to show a button on the "you're not connected" error screen. However, obviously in this case this will NOT suffice.

So I'm considering using a local proxy cache server to do the job for Chrome. However, I have no experience with setting up such a cache server, and so far googling it has turned up nothing which quite fits my description.

Any recommendations and instructions on how to do this?

Thank you very much for your time and concern

Comment: Although the job is for W8, it would help to know in which OS you're developing, at least.